# Delete duplicate cells in excel across tabs

Tags: vba, excel, tabs

**For a keyword that appears across different tabs in Excel, what is the simplest way to delete the duplicate keywords in other tabs?**

In below example, keyword "Fish Burger Deluxe" appears in tabs Tomato, Hamburger, Fish, Protein and Burger King - What should I do to delete the value "Fish Burger Deluxe" from Hamburger, Fish, Protein, and Burger King?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445060/vba-script-to-compare-2-sheets-and-delete-duplicated-cells-big-search-range) script however not sure if it applies to my exact situation.

I am familiar with excel formulas, but am a macro and VBA noob... I am confident I could learn however don't know where to start for this situation.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Link to picture of example:
[Example of duplicate keyword across tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhZhk.jpg)

Comment: To get started with VBA, I'd do this:  Turn on the macro recorder.  Click a sheet name, do a find for "Fish Burger Deluxe".  When it finds a cell, then delete that cell, and find again. Then, click the next sheet, repeat.  After two repetitions, take a look at the created macro and see if you can figure out how you can tweak it to loop through the multiple names, etc. Then post here with any questions!

Comment: you want to delete the cell's content, or delete the entire row?

Comment: Thank you BruceWayne, playing around with Macros and trying to break it down into individual actions, will report back soon with specific questions!

A.S.H.- Either would be fine really, whichever is easier. In the tabs there are only 2 columns of data.

Comment: @sikorloa Neither is difficult, but the code will be different depending on what you want to do.  Also, what do you want to happen after you delete the cell or row?  If you delete a row, all the rows below will move up; if you delete a cell, only the cells in that column will move up.  Also note the difference between `Delete` and `Clear`